# Cross domain jquery ajax (Jsonp): Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : (colon)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I've been trying to pull data from the steam api, and have had no luck because I always get the above error. Here is the code I am using:

```
var steamurl = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistory/V001/?key=[keyomitted]&account_id=38440257&Matches_Requested=10";
function populate_api(){
    var json;
        $.ajax({ 
            'url': steamurl,
            'dataType': "jsonp",
            'success': function (data) {
                alert('success');
                json = data;
            }
        });
}
```

I omitted my API key.
I have looked at many other posts, and cannot figure out where the problem is. I have tried using Jsonp, regular json, I have also tried using `"&callback=?"` after `steamurl`, but to no avail.

Comment: can you share the response format from the sever

Comment: I don't think that API supports JSONP, only JSON.

Comment: See https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/Feedback#API_Considerations_for_Web_Developers

Comment: @Barmar I have also tried JSON as the datatype with and without the callback and it did not work.

Comment: @ArunPJohny forgive my inexperience, but how do I find the response from the server? I do not feel as though I am getting one.

Comment: As per the link shared above they do not directly support web API's since they require the API key to be kept secret... in a web api it won't be secret as anybody could read the contents of the js file

Comment: JSON won't work because of the same-origin policy.

Comment: Now the solution as far as I can tell is to make your server as a proxy and sent the ajax requests to your webserver and from there using your server side techonology(java/PHP etc) sent a request to the said API and return the value returned from the API call to the browser

Comment: @ArunPJohny I see so I cannot use JSONP as it is not compatible, and I cannot use JSON because of the same-origin policy? Does this mean I will have to find another way to take the JSON from the api?

Comment: you can't use javascript to get the response from the said resource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution for this is to add a local proxy that your jQuery code will call. Your proxy will be server side code (PHP, Python, Ruby, etc) that forwards the query on to Valve and then returns it to your jQuery call. You will, however, have to use one of their supported formats (of which JSONP is not one).

A high level view of what you'll be doing:

- Create PHP file that accepts the parameters jQuery will be passing. In this case, it looks like account ID and matches you want to receive. Do not pass the API key, this should be stored in the PHP file
- In PHP, build your `steamurl` using the stored API key, and the two passed values
- Issue a call to the Valve servers using this `steamurl` and retrieve the results.
- Return this response to your ajax call

Your PHP will look something like this (and should include more error checking since I am just taking the `$_GET` values as gospel:

```
$matches = $_GET['matches'];
$acct = $_GET['accountid'];
$APIKEY = <YOURKEYHERE>;

$steamurl = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistory/V001/?key=$APIKEY&account_id=$acct&Matches_Requested=$matches&format=json";
$json_object= file_get_contents($steamurl);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json_object;
```

Now you can use jQuery to parse this JSON response.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a game plan where I was a bit lost. :)