# Uncaught SyntaxError while calling JSON from Dota 2 match history API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm making an attempt to call match history for a Steam user utilizing Dota 2's match API (found here: http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=47115).

I have tried both using `$.ajax` and `$.getJSON` but both methods give errors.

Chrome:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :                 api.Steampowered.com/:2`

and in FireFox:
`SyntaxError: missing ; before statement                                   V001:2`

Viewing the line where the code is erroring shows the JSON data that I want to get
`{
    "result": {
        "status": 1,
        "num_results": 1,
        "total_results": 500,
        "results_remaining": 499,
        "matches": [
            {
                "match_id": 583031457,
                "match_seq_num": 530629087,
                "start_time": 1396000424,
                "lobby_type": 0,
                "players": [
                    {
                        "account_id": 4294967295,
                        "player_slot": 0,
                        "hero_id": 14
                    },
etc....`

**Why is this erroring and what can I do to resolve the issue?**

Here is the most recent version of my javascript (after multiple attempts to fix it):

```
var apiURL = "https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistory/V001/?";
var apiKey = "key=*My account's API key*";
var steamID = "&account_id=37828178";
var matchesNum = "&matches_requested=1";
var callBack = "&jsoncallback=?";

$.ajax({
    url: apiURL + apiKey + steamID + matchesNum + callBack,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //Code using the data I've accessed
    }
});`
```

Comment: Valve does not have a cross domain policy that would allow this to work. However, there is a work around posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701750/cross-domain-jquery-ajax-jsonp-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-colo/21704177#21704177

Comment: @Andy I'm using C# on this particular website, is PHP still a viable way to accomplish this?

Comment: PHP is just an example. You could build the same functionality in the C# application and return it to your javascript like the php is doing.